# Horizontally flip a image texture with MeshPhongMaterial in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I've tried the following with MeshBasicMaterial:

```
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.repeat.x = - 1;
```

And it works, but only with this specific material.

I'd like to know how to do the same on either MeshLambertMaterial or MeshPhongMaterial.

**UPDATED**

I've created a live example here: http://jsbin.com/jecaqi/18/edit?js,output

In this example, I flipped the image texture with MeshBasicMaterial(mesh_basic) on the left side one. My purpose is to do exact the same thing on the right one with MeshPhongMaterial(mesh_phong).

Comment: Can you provide a live example showing the problem?

Comment: I've created an example here: http://jsbin.com/jecaqi/edit?js,output

Comment: (1) Your jsbin is not implementing the code in your post. Why not? (2) Your texture is not a power of 2 in size. Always look at the debug console for error/warning messages.

Comment: Hi @WestLangley, I don't really know what you mean by "not implementing the code in your post", the RepeatWrapping one? If so, it's because I changed it to THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping to solve the warning message your (2) mentioned. And both of them won't work on flipping the image texture.

Comment: I've created an updated example: http://jsbin.com/jecaqi/12/edit?js,output to completely match the code I've mentioned in my post. p.s. I commented out line 45 to express the fact it doesn't work.

Comment: (1) Your fiddle #12 does not match the code in your post, and (2) you did not make the texture a power-of-two. If you do that, it should work as expected.

Comment: (1) fiddle#18 line:15 => tx.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping; and line:45 => mesh_phong.scale.x = -1; (2) both the texture and the image source are now power-of-two. url: http://jsbin.com/jecaqi/18/edit?js,output

Comment: As I said, if you make the code in the fiddle match the code in your post, it works. You are not doing that for some reason. Why not?

Comment: @WestLangley I'm sorry I misunderstood your point, it works when I added the texture.repeat.x = -1; Thanks a million for your time.

Comment: You knew how to do it all along -- well, except for the POT part. : - )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to horizontally flip and an image on a texture, you can do so by using the following pattern:

```
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.repeat.x = - 1;
```

You also need to make sure that the image is a power-of-two (POT).

three.js r.71